# Ionic Cordova Social Share plugin - cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

So I've been on this for 3 days now... 
Tried several tutorials like [this](http://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-add-social-sharing-for-your-ionic-app/) one, and tried after the original page [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/), and read the GitHub description a thousand times.

Versions I'm using:

```
$ npm -v
3.7.3

$ cordova -v
6.1.0 (cordova-lib@undefined)

$ ionic -v
1.7.14
```

The error I'm getting in Chrome browser: **Cannot read property 'socialsharing' of undefined**. On android or ios phone nothing happens if buttons are pressed. Not even error function call.

**The app.js + controller:** (notice I'm trying with window.plugins and without .plugins as well!)

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

  .controller('shareCtrl',['$scope',function($scope) {

     $scope.facebookShare=function(){
      window.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook('Digital Signature Maker', null /* img */, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prantikv.digitalsignaturemaker" /* url */, null, 
        function(errormsg){alert("Error: Cannot Share")});
     }

     $scope.whatsappShare=function(){
      window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('Digital Signature Maker', null /* img */, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prantikv.digitalsignaturemaker" /* url */, null, 
        function(errormsg){alert("Error: Cannot Share")});
```

}

I have tried to install even manually, and here there was a different error. When I inserted SocialSharing.js into index.html (before cordova.js), Chrome console said: **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**, which is in  line 1 of SocialSharing.js:

```
var cordova = require('cordova');
```

So I have installed require.sj (npm install -g requirejs) with success and then tried manually but whole different kind of errors appeared.

Tried re installing the plugin or remove and add again platforms, but no change.

Not sure if it's related, but have tried to use ngCordova's $cordovaFileOpener2 and that one always gave the error of undefined for cordova. (Didn't work on actual phone either)

Appreciate any help!
Thanks

**UPDATE:** 
I have pasted in all of my .js file content above.

Please note that, I have successfully installed the share plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" for android
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>    
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-view view-title="Share">
      <ion-content ng-controller="shareCtrl">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                <b> Share this app</b>
            </div>
         <ul class="list">
           <li class="item" id="displayLabel">

            <button class="button button-block button-royal item-icon-left" ng-click="whatsappShare()">
                <i class="icon ion-social-whatsapp"></i>
                  WhatsApp
          </button>
          </li>

           <li class="item" id="displayLabel">

            <button class="button button-block button-royal item-icon-left" ng-click="facebookShare()">
                <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
                  facebook
          </button>
          </li>

          <li class="item" id="displayLabel">     
            <button class="button button-block button-royal item-icon-left" ng-click="OtherShare()">
                 <i class="icon ion-android-share-alt"></i>
                  Other
          </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried cordova social sharing plugin?...if not try by installing this plugin..."cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing"

Comment: sorry I was tired yesterday, and forgot to mention but that is the one I've been trying to get to work :) and yes it's installed

Answer (score 2):

Actually Plugins provide access to device and platform functionality that is ordinarily unavailable to web-based apps. So you may not achieve plugin functionality on browser.

You can achieve **on device(android/ios/emulator)** using either by using Plugin or ngCordova.js file

**Using Plugin**

***Installation:*** 
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

***Usage:***

```
.controller('ShareCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.whatsappShare = function(){
        if(window.plugins.socialsharing) {
        window.plugins.socialsharing.canShareVia('whatsapp',
            'msg', null, null, null,
            function (e) {
                //do something
            },
            function (e) {
               //error occured
            });
       }
    }
})
```

**Using ng-Cordova**

***Installation:*** Add ng-cordova file in your project and include it in index.html file

`<script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>`

***Usage***:

```
.controller('ShareCtrl', function ($scope,$cordovaSocialSharing) {
   $scope.shareByWhatsApp = function() {
        $cordovaSocialSharing
            .shareViaWhatsApp('sharedMsg', "", shareAppLink)
            .then(function(result) {
            }, function(err) {
                // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
                alert("error : "+err);
            });
    };
})
```

Comment: I have tried every possibility of combination of what you proposed, with installing/uninstalling cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing, adding removing ng-cordova.js, but to no avail. The same error appears in Chrome (socialsharing undef), and in Android nothing happens. I am tring with fb, whatsapp, share.

Comment: try using like this,  if(window.plugins && window.plugins.socialsharing) {}, it may check for plugin 1st and then exec function

Comment: This helped me after a serious headache with `$window.plugins` being undefined using [this other version][1] by the same guy. Thanks


  [1]: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin